# Error while writing in Excel file with xlutils.copy

Tags: python

I try to write a value in Excel file (format `.xlsx`).

So I wrote this code:

```
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
from robot.api import logger

def set_value_in_excel(filename, sheet_num, row_index, column_index, value):
    logger.console(filename) // myfile.xlsx
    logger.console(sheet_num) // 0
    logger.console(row_index) // 1
    logger.console(column_index) // 3
    logger.console(value) // False
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    wb = copy(rb)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet(int(sheet_num))
    sheet.write(row_index, column_index, value)
    wb.save(filename)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: column index ('3') not an int in range(256)

Could you please help me?

Comment: `'3'` isn't an `int`. It's going to be hard to work out exactly what the problem is without a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of the code that's failing, including the complete Traceback.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Need to convert some values in `int`.

```
sheet.write(int(row_index), int(column_index), value)
```